# Is there any safe way to 're-route' requirejs 1.0 module dependencies?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In the RequireJS 1.0 api, in a scenario where you have 'Module B' that depends on 'Module A', and 'Module A' depends on some 'Module C' that you don't want 'Module B' to know about, is the best option to point 'Module C' to some path to a no-op module?

```
// with RequireJS 1.0 api:

define('ModuleA', ['ModuleC'], function(){
  // Module C makes sense here, but down in the definition for Module B,
  // Module C is dangerous.
})

// 2. here's an approach that comes to mind, but I think it's nasty:
require.config({
  paths: {
    'ModuleC': '/path/to/no-op/module'
  }
})

define('ModuleB', ['ModuleA'], function(){
  // 1. how do I depend on 'ModuleA' without depending on 'ModuleC'?
})
```

Basically, I want to re-use some code from Module A in Module B, but without including Module C, which tries to call code that doesn't exist in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleB` won't know about `ModuleC` (unless `ModuleA` makes it accessible somehow). However, if `ModuleB` requires `ModuleA` and `ModuleA` requires `ModuleC` then, yes, `ModuleB` *requires* the loading of `ModuleC` through `ModuleA`, even if `ModuleB` can't use it.

Just ensure your dependent module is exported correctly and passed as the argument for your defined module so it's only accessible in your defined modules' scope:

```
define('ModuleA', ['ModuleC'], function(ModuleC){
  // ModuleC, passed as an argument, is only accessible here.
});

define('ModuleB', ['ModuleA'], function(ModuleA){
  // Though ModuleC has been downloaded b/c ModuleA requires it, 
  // Only ModuleA is available within this scope.
});
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is avoid loading `ModuleC` here. In my case, it's a problem for that code to even load on the page :(

Comment: @RaulFenty Sounds like you're not requiring well-written modules. Right from the Require Docs: "A module is different from a traditional script file in that it defines a well-scoped object that avoids polluting the global namespace." If `ModuleC` is written as such, then there would be no issue with loading it as a requirement of `ModuleA`